# Why no results when executing PLSQL procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have written the following PLSQL procedure:

```sql
create or replace procedure lrt_bericht (current_date in VARCHAR2, last_date in VARCHAR2) as
   calendar_week VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    calendar_week := EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)||'_'||to_char(to_date(current_date,'DD.MM.YYYY'),'IW');

    delete from astrid_liste_history
    where link_to_uts is null;

    insert into astrid_liste_bericht
    (Link_to_UTS,Incident_Number,CI_Plus,Site_ID,Anzahl_CI_ID,Anzahl_Zellen,Status_690,Service_Affecting,Incident_Work_Info_Notes,Target_Date,Incident_Work_Info_Summary,Assigned_Group,Submit_Date_max,Last_Modified_Day,Region_CI_Plus,WEATHERMAP_LONGTERM,Incident_Summary,Reported_Date,Status,Company,Incident_Notes,Supercluster,CI_Plus_Cons_Top65,CI_Plus_Cons_Region,CI_Plus_Cons_Year,Last_LRI_Update,Link_to_ATEA,Bereich_Gruppe,Connect_Prio,Connect_Pop_Rank,Categorization_Tier_1,Categorization_Tier_2,Categorization_Tier_3,Date_Import,Time_Import) 
    select * 
    from astrid_liste_history
    where astrid_liste_history.date_import = current_date;

    update astrid_liste_bericht
    set Closed_In_CW = calendar_week
    where
    incident_number in
    (select incident_number from astrid_liste_bericht where date_import = last_date
    and INCIDENT_WORK_INFO_SUMMARY like '%Volker%'
    minus
    select incident_number from astrid_liste_bericht where date_import = current_date)
    ;

    update astrid_liste_bericht
    set Closed_In_CW = NULL
    where date_import not in (last_date)
    and Closed_In_CW = calendar_week;

    update astrid_liste_bericht
    set ADPW = 'Yes'
    where
    closed_in_cw = calendar_week
    and upper(INCIDENT_SUMMARY) like '%ADPW%';

    update astrid_liste_bericht
    set ADPW = 'No'
    where
    closed_in_cw = calendar_week
    and upper(INCIDENT_SUMMARY) not like '%ADPW%';

    COMMIT;
END lrt_bericht;
```

It compiles sucessfully but after trying to execute it:

```sql
begin
lrt_bericht('10.11.2019','03.11.2019');
end;
```

there is no data written into the astrid_liste_bericht table.

However, if I execute manually every step in the procedure, at the end I can see the data being added/updated in the astrid_liste_bericht table.

Do you have any idea why this happens and what should I do in oder to make the data be updated in the astrid_liste_bericht table via the procedure?

Comment: why do you store `date_import` columns as string instead of date type ?

Comment: I have no oracle experience, but could it be some date format incompatibility problem? I can see that your parameters are not of any date type.

Comment: Run this query outside of the procedure:

    select * 
    from astrid_liste_history
    where astrid_liste_history.date_import = current_date;

Does it give you any data?

Comment: You should rename your `current_date` parameter, as this is already [the name of an Oracle function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CURRENT_DATE.html).

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like an issue with date mismatch. What is the column type of astrid_liste_history.date_import.

Can you run this query and confirm if data comes back from sql prompt

select * 
    from astrid_liste_history
    where astrid_liste_history.date_import = current_date ;

Replace this current_date  with whatever date you are passing to Proc.

Adding test script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_proc
(
   current_date1 IN VARCHAR2
  ,last_date     IN VARCHAR2
) AS
   calendar_week VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
   calendar_week := extract(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) || '_' ||
                    to_char(to_date(current_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'IW');

   INSERT INTO temp
      (temp1)
      SELECT 1 FROM temp2 WHERE temp2.date_import = current_date1;

   COMMIT;
END temp_proc;
/

CREATE TABLE temp(temp1 VARCHAR2(100));
/
CREATE TABLE temp2(date_import VARCHAR2(100));
/
INSERT INTO temp2 VALUES('10.11.2019')

SELECT 1 FROM temp2 WHERE temp2.date_import = '10.11.2019';

SET serveroutput ON
BEGIN
temp_proc('10.11.2019', NULL);

END;
/

   select *
   from temp;
```

Comment: So I ran: select count(*) from astrid_liste_history where astrid_liste_history.date_import = '10.11.2019'  and there are 758 entries.

Comment: Strange , taking a stab in the dark now but could you add exception block to your proc and try executing it again . also before calling it you - set serveroutput on

Comment: So I have icnluded in the procedure:

EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SQLCODE);
 
Then I executed:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

begin
lrt_bericht('10.11.2019','03.11.2019');
end;

and no exception is displayed

Comment: If there was an exception it would propagate to the caller automatically and you would know about it. Adding a `when others then dbms_output` handler makes any exception less visible, not more.

Comment: I can see the issue is with the variable 'current_date' this is picking Oracle's internal function and gives me an exception 'Not a Valid Month' . Could you change this variable name and then try again. I have appended my test script in the original answer - have a look. The script works fine post renaming current_date